# How do I use SyncFusion Signature Box

Tags: asp.net, webforms, syncfusion

I'll be frank, I have little to no experience in asp.net. I've been building a website in Web Forms for a past few weeks. I would like to put a Signature control on a page on this site. I'm using SyncFusion.

I tried to add it to a new web form for testing;

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test.aspx.vb" Inherits="test" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Syncfusion.EJ.Web, Version=14.4460.0.15, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" Namespace="Syncfusion.JavaScript.Web" TagPrefix="ej" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ej:Signature ID="Signature1" runat="server"></ej:Signature>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But all I get is a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is the page source in the empty browser;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./test.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
typeof EJ_ClientSideOnPostBack == 'function' && EJ_ClientSideOnPostBack();
return true;
}
//]]>
</script>

<div>
    <div id="Signature1"></div>
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="75BBA7D6" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$("#Signature1").ejSignature({"strokeWidth":2,"enabled":true,"height":"400px","backgroundColor":"#ffffff","strokeColor":"#000000","clientId":"Signature1","uniqueId":"Signature1"});
//]]>
</script>
</form>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"958d69901e2943e493e9b4da9976b691"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:55500/690a8379ccf649d289724e7760d89595/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion Signature doesn't have any default height or width value. It has the both the height and width as 100% by default.It fits inside the given div. Hence we need to set the **height** value for the signature.

```asp
<div>
    <ej:Signature ID="Signature1" height="400px" runat="server"></ej:Signature>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still getting a blank page. Is there a way to check what's actually loading in ASP.NET? I'm including my page source.